# Proof of rigidity lemma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, schemes

I have problems to understand a proof in [this paper](https://www.pierrickdartois.fr/homepage/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/seminar_report.pdf) by Pierrick Dartois on Abelian varieties:

**Theorem 1.13 (rigidity lemma).** Let $ \varphi: X \times_k Y \to Z$ be a morphism of $k$-schemes. Assume that $X$ is proper and geometrically integral, that $ X \times_k Y $ is geometrically irreducible, that $ Z$ is separated and that there exist $ k$-valued points $x_0 ∈ X(k), y_0 ∈ Y(k) $  and $z_0 ∈ Z(k)$ such that: $  \varphi(X \times \{y_0\}) = \{z_0\} =  \varphi({x_0} \times Y)$ Then, $ \varphi(X \times Y) = \{ z_0 \}$.

The proof starts with:

**Proof.** One can easily see that the properties of the theorem are invariant under base change, so we can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. Let $U_0$ be an open affine neighborhood of $z_0$ ...

*Question:* Why $ k$ can be assumed to be algebraically closed? Since all properties of the schemes in the assumptions are geometrically, the conditions not change if we replace the schemes by fibre products $ X \times \text{Spec} (\overline{k})$ with algebraic closure of $k$. But having proved the lemma for them, how can we derive the statement for schemes over not algebraically closed $k$?

*Remark:* I noticed that the proof strategy is rather similar with lemma 1.12 in [these notes](http://van-der-geer.nl/%7Egerard/AV.pdf) by by Moonen & Geer with one exception that there is not assumed the existence of a $k$-point $x_0 ∈ X(k)$. This can be only assured after base change to algebraic closure. But the problem remains the same: how to retain the claim after hsving proved it for algebraic closed base field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varphi_{\bar{k}}(X_{\bar{k}} \times_{\bar{k}} Y_{\bar{k}})=\{z_0\}$ then since $\varphi(X\times Y) \subset \varphi_{\bar{k}}(X_{\bar{k}} \times_{\bar{k}} Y_{\bar{k}})$ we also have $\varphi(X\times Y)\subset\{z_0\}$.

Comment: I see, so here in case of Dartois' paper that's finally  a pure diagram-chasing conclusion at all. Do you maybe see if it's possible  to argue in similar way to justify the reduction to $ k =\overline{k}$ in case of the Moonen & van der Geer's Rigidity lemma in the notes in second link? It looks conceptionally rather similar to the first problem - in sense of that it appears that it can be somehow concluded similarly by a diagram chase after having proved it for $\overline{k}$ - but finally I not find an argument to obtain the arrow $Y \to Z$ at the "bottom" of the square